# Error: RoleArn is not supported for target arn:aws:automation:ap-south-1:action/EBSCreateSnapshot/EBSCreateSnapshot (Service: AmazonCloudWatchEvents)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, roles

I have used the below cloudformation template code. The issue is, if I did not use 'RoleArn' under 'Targets' the script is running and there is no error but role is not attached under targets and snapshot of the ebs volume is also not created. If I include 'RoleArn' under 'Targets' Iam getting the same error as mentioned above. I have created an volume,EBSsnapshot role and Snapshot rule.
The following is the respective code:

```
EBSVolume:
 Type: 'AWS::EC2::Volume'
 Properties:
   Size: 1
   AvailabilityZone: ap-south-1a
EBSSnapshotRole:
 Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
 Properties:
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Version: 2012-10-17
    Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          Service:
            - events.amazonaws.com
            - ec2.amazonaws.com
        Action:
          - 'sts:AssumeRole'
   Path: /
   Policies:
    - PolicyName: root
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'ec2:CreateSnapshot'
            Resource: '*'
EBSSnapshotRule:
 Type: 'AWS::Events::Rule'
 Properties:
  Description: creates a daily snapshot of EBS volume (1 a.m.)
  ScheduleExpression: cron(0 1 * * ? *)
  State: ENABLED
  RoleArn: !GetAtt
    - EBSSnapshotRole
    - Arn
  Name:
    Ref: 'AWS::StackName'
  Targets:
    - Arn:
        'Fn::Join':
          - ''
          - - 'arn:aws:automation:'
            - Ref: 'AWS::Region'
            - ':'
            - Ref: 'AWS::AccountId'
            - ':action/'
            - EBSCreateSnapshot/EBSCreateSnapshot_
            - Ref: 'AWS::StackName'
      Input: 
        'Fn::Join':
          - ''
          - - '"'
            - !Ref EBSVolume
            - '"'                  
      RoleArn: !GetAtt
         - EBSSnapshotRole
         - Arn
      Id: EBSVolume
```

Comment: What exactly is EBSSnapshotRole?

Comment: @Marcin I have given the complete code now. Please check